# MongoDB replica set (1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbitor) copy/clone on another environmnet

Tags: mongodb, azure

I am able to clone replica set mongo servers(Azure VM) and spin up new replica set server(Azure VM). 
I am getting stuck at a point as new VMs will have different IP hence replica set configuration will not work . 
Is there a way; mongo config file or commands I can change replica set configuration to work properly.
My data folders and config files are exactly same because I spin up new VM in different subscription which is exactly same.

Comment: Please describe your setup more exactly: are all your VMs IPs on the net ? Are some in a non public subnet ?

Comment: @FreudChicken My Mongo server VMs are in a subscription that contains other VMs for sitecore that communicates with MongoVM. MOngo VMs can't be accessed via Public IPs. I am trying to replicate same servers for another subscription. Able to create exact copy . I want to know is there way in mogo to edit/modify replica set configuration as my new Mongo VMs have everything except replica set configuration as it contains replica configuration from previous subscription.

Comment: Still kind of unclear: note that a replicaset is meant for keep changing data in sync on different instances of mongodb. If you just want to copy a snapshot, you do not need a replicaset at all

Comment: @FreudChicken I have environment up and running . I have to create another environment that should be exact replica of my running environment. I am able to spin up exactly same replica VMs, but as my new VMs will have different IPs hence my configuration of MongoDB replica set that was copied to this new environment will not work. I want to know is there a way to just change/modify..replicaset config

Comment: check, so once you have set up your new environment, it does not have to stay in sync with the old one you copied from?

Comment: No new one has not to be in sync for that I can use backup and restore option that I know, but I am not aware of modifying replicaset with new IPS..I just know how to create new replica set..so was wondering instead of creating new replicaset and doing backup restore can I just modify config .how to achieve that